# How to get text from element value in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress, automation-testing

My problem is I created two methods that will generate a random first name and random last name from the arrays of names. When the test executes the first and the last name methods, I want to somehow get those two values and combine them into an email in the specific format -> "firstName.lastName@gmail.com".

But I don't know how to do it and I can't find the answer that works. Keep in mind I work in Cypress for a few days. Below is the photo of the fields and HTML of the element (both are the same in terms of where the value is stored).

```js
function generateEmail(){
  var email = cy.get("input[placeholder='Enter first name']") + "." +  
    cy.get("input[placeholder='Enter last name']") + "@gmail.com"
  return email
}
```

[image]

I don't know what to use in order to get the text from the value attribute.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so we can make alterations.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking you will use `.then()` to get a value from `cy.get()` but since they are inputs you also need `.invoke('val')` to extract the value entered into the `<input>`.

Return the whole chain and use it with `.then()`, or create a custom command instead of a function.

```js
function generateEmail() { 
  return cy.get("input[placeholder='Enter first name']").invoke('val')
    .then(first => {
      cy.get("input[placeholder='Enter last name']").invoke('val')
        .then(last => {
          return first  + "." + last + "@gmail.com"
        })
    })
}

...

generateEmail()
  .then(email => {
    expect(email).to.eq('John.Smith@gmail.com)  // it works!
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function generateEmail() {
return Promise.all([
    cy.get("input[placeholder='Enter first name']").invoke('val'),
    cy.get("input[placeholder='Enter last name']").invoke('val')
  ]).then(([firstName, lastName]) => {
    const email = `${firstName}.${lastName}@gmail.com`;
    return email;
  });
}
```

Call generateEmail funtion

```
 generateEmail().then((email) => {
      console.log(email);
    });
```

Call Another Way

```
async function getEmail() {
  const email = await generateEmail();
  console.log(email);
}

getEmail();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I got the return of the "undefined.undefined@gmail.com".

Comment: @millanche try this code, I hope this time helps you...